Spak SQL still shows replaced columns in Hive table
I've created a table via Hive CLI with these commands:
CREATE TABLE a (id INT, c1 INT) PARTITIONED BY (b BOOLEAN);

INSERT INTO TABLE a PARTITION (b='true') VALUES (1,1),(2,2);
INSERT INTO TABLE a PARTITION (b='false') VALUES (3,3),(4,4);

And then I've replaced column:
ALTER TABLE a PARTITION (b='false') REPLACE COLUMNS (id INT);

When I'm describing table from Hive CLI it shows just two columns. It's expected because c1 column was removed by replace command.
DESCRIBE a PARTITION (b='false');
hive> DESCRIBE a PARTITION (b='false');
OK
id                      int
b                       boolean

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

b                       boolean
Time taken: 0.161 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
hive>

But Spark SQL CLI still shows three columns:
spark-sql> DESCRIBE a PARTITION (b='false');
id  int NULL
c1  int NULL
b   boolean NULL
# Partition Information
# col_name  data_type   comment
b   boolean NULL
Time taken: 0.189 seconds, Fetched 6 row(s)
spark-sql>

Is it expected behavior? How can I get the same behavior from Spark SQL?
I've already tried REFRESH TABLE command for Spark but it didn't help. Also, my hive-site.xml is the same as in Hive and I'm using the same Hive Metastore.
Will be grateful for any help!
